# How Can i Test a Service Attempting to Open an NgBootstrap Modal With a Component as Content?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a simple service that injects `NgbModal` and tries to programmatically open a modal if a request error occurs:

```
handleError = (error): Observable<any> => {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ChangeError);
  return Observable.throw(error);
};
```

When i try to test the service containing this method, instantiation fails with the message `Error: No component factory found for NgbModalBackdrop. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`. However it is defined in the module's `@NgModule` metadata:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModal
  ],
  declarations: [
    FirstComponent,
    SecondComponent
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [
    ChangeError, 
    NgbModalBackdrop
  ]
})
export class MyModule {  }
```

Any ideas to resolve this are greatly appreciated. When run in the browser the code executes without generating an exception, but fails to actually open a modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by changing `imports` member of the the configuration object passed as the argument to `TestBed.configureTestingModule` from `imports: [NgbModal, ...]` to `imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...]`

Before :

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [NgbModal, ...]
  ...
}
```

After:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...]
  ...
}
```

Seems a bit clunky, but works.

Comment: How are you testing whether the modal is actually added to the page (if you are)? I'm having trouble getting anything to return with `By.css()` even though in the Karma browser page, the modal is open.

Comment: I mock `NgbModal` and spy the `open` method, then i verify that the spy was called. If the modal returns something, you will need the spy to return something like `{result: Promise.resolve(myModalResult)}`.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. What if you need to test the content within the modal (e.g. if it's dynamic)?

Comment: I use a component as the modal's content and test that component in isolation.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I'm still trying to get my head around thinking that way instead of "the whole page is a component" It always seems to introduce difficulties in passing data down and bubbling actions up that don't exist if you keep stuff in one component. So easier to develop up front, harder to test.